# The network path was not found C# and Oracle

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio-2015

I had this application done for mySQL, but now I have to remake it for oracle. So now I am running into this

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>
> The network path was not found
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of
>   the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more
>   information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The network
>   path was not found
>
> Source Error:
>
> Line 222:                //By department result. Line 223:
>   GridDatasource1(); Line 224:                GridView1.DataBind(); Line
>   225:                //End of by department result. Line 226:
>   //Multiple surname results.
>
> Source File: C:\Users\tomas.filip\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Default.aspx.cs    Line:
>   224
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [Win32Exception (0x80004005): The network path was not found]
>
> [SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific
>   error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The
>   server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance
>   name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote
>   connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not
>   open a connection to SQL Server)]
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity
>   identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential
>   credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString
>   newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString
>   userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, String accessToken, Boolean
>   applyTransientFaultHandling) +1418
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions
>   options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo,
>   DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection,
>   DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +470
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool
>   pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options,
>   DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +70
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +945
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection
>   owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal
>   oldConnection) +114
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean
>   allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +1637
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection) +117
>
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection
>   owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions
>   userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal&
>   connection) +267
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection
>   outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
>   TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions) +318
>
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +132
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1
>   retry) +246    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open() +122
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset,
>   DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String
>   srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +177
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, Int32
>   startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command,
>   CommandBehavior behavior) +182
>   System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataSet dataSet, String
>   srcTable) +123
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSourceView.ExecuteSelect(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments) +2964
>   System.Web.UI.DataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments
>   arguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +26
>   WebApplication1._Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   C:\Users\tomas.filip\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2015\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\Default.aspx.cs:224
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +11828965
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +150    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean
>   includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +1735

There are the areas of code which are realted to this.

```
//By department result.
GridDatasource1();
GridView1.DataBind();
//End of by department result.
```

The function

```
protected void GridDatasource1()
        {
            SqlDataSource SqlDataSource2 = new SqlDataSource();
            SqlDataSource2.ID = "SqlDataSource2";
            this.Page.Controls.Add(SqlDataSource2);
            SqlDataSource2.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlDataSource2.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM v_employees_intr where PLACE  like '" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "' ORDER BY '" + RadioButtonList1.SelectedValue + "' ASC;";
            GridView1.DataSource = SqlDataSource2;         
        }
```

And the conString

```
<add name="conString" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=epcepc091:1521/XE;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=SYSTEM;Password=Epce12345" providerName="System.Data.OracleClient" />
```

I was trying to find the solution but unsuccesfuly. I will be greatefull for any help. Thanks.

Comment: This seems to be wrong: _DATA SOURCE=epcepc091:1521/XE_ should you put the port number as the last part _epcepc091/XE:1521_

Comment: Well, thats not it :/

Comment: The exception points to an SqlConnection failing but this should not be the case with a ProviderName set to Oracle libraries. It is like the ProviderName is wrong. Can you try to set the ProviderName property directly in code and not implicitly via the ConnectionString?

Comment: Hey man thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So thanks to Seve, thanks you really
all I had to do was add

```
SqlDataSource2.ProviderName = "System.Data.OracleClient";
```

Dont know why it wasnt working within Web.config. Thank you Steve.